# Symmetric groups and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices, determinant

[image]

I am currently working through this question. I have completed part (a) and (c), however I am unable to make any progress with (b). I know $S_n$ is the symmetric group on n symbols, and that it has order n!, so it is clear that there will be $n!/2$ disjoint pairs, however I'm not sure why they are of the form given, or even what the form actually represents. I believe it is something to do with the fact $A^{(i)}=A^{(j)}$ but cannot say much more than that. Can anyone show me how best to approach this?

Comment: Have you heard of the alternating group $A_n$?

Comment: @Alqatrkapa I have studied the alternating group (in minor detail!) in another course, I know of it to be the set of even permutations in $S_n$

Comment: Consider elements of the alternating group $\sigma \in A_n$. Then, since the sign of a permutation is odd, we know that $\sigma(i,j)$ will be odd. Thus we partition $S_n$ into $A_n$ and $(i,j)A_n$. Could we use this to make pairs of the form in part b?

Comment: @alqatrkapa Can we partition $S_n$ into $A_n(i, i)=A_n$ and $A_n(i,j)$ so that the even permutations and odd permutations are in either respectively. As $A_n \cup A_n(i,j) = S_n$ and the order of $S_n$ is $n!$, the order of $A_n(i,j)$ is $n!/2$. Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

The alternating group $A_n$ is the subgroup of $S_n$ which contains all the even permutations of $S_n$ i.e. with signature $1$ and let

$$\phi: S_n\to S_n,\quad \sigma\mapsto \sigma(i,j)$$
then it's easy to see that $\phi$ is a bijection hence $A_n$ and $\phi(A_n)$ have the same cardinal and since they are disjoint then the cardinal of $A_n$ is $\frac{n!}{2}$ and if $\sigma\in A_n$ then $\phi(\sigma)=\sigma(i,j)\in\phi(A_n)$ and the result follows.

Comment: Great! @Alqatrkapa Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this without $A_n$?

Comment: Well, each pair necessarily contains one even permutation and one odd permutation, so even if your solution is formulated without explicit mention of $A_n$ it will still be true that each pair is formed by an even permutation $\sigma$ and its product with $(i,j)$.